# column max with list of matrices

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Given a list of numpy `2d`-arrays of size `mxn`, what is the best way to get an array of size `n` (number of columns of each matrix in the list) where the `i`-the value of the array is the maximum of column `i`, across all matrices in the list?

Comment: You are mixing `matrix` and `array` in your question and please clarify what the `i`th value of a 2D array is meant to be. 2D arrays have a 1D-array at the `i`th position not a value

Comment: If the 2d arrays are all the same size, you can convert the list into a 3d array, and choose your `max` over one or more of the dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np

>>> a = np.array([[1,11,5,2], [3,9,1,12], [5,7,7,1]])
>>> a
array([[ 1, 11,  5,  2],
       [ 3,  9,  1, 12],
       [ 5,  7,  7,  1]])
```

Max by column

```
>>> a.max(axis=0)
array([ 5, 11,  7, 12])
```

Max by row

```
>>> a.max(axis=1)
array([11, 12,  7])
```

If you have a list of 2D numpy arrays:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,11,5,2], [3,9,1,12], [5,7,7,1]])
>>> b = np.array([[2,4,6,8],[1,3,2,1],[5,6,7,8]])
>>> l = [a,b]
```

You can use a list comprehension

```
>>> [i.max(axis=0) for i in l]
[array([ 5, 11,  7, 12]),
 array([5, 6, 7, 8])]

>>> [i.max(axis=1) for i in l]
[array([11, 12,  7]),
 array([8, 3, 8])]
```

Comment: I think the latest should be applied to the second latest. The final result should be a 1d array. In this case, it'd be [5, 11, 7, 12]

Comment: @Bob instead of a Python list, you can make a numpy array of the returned list of maximums. Then you can do one final `.max` to get a single 1D array.

Answer (score 0):

You can first stack the arrays vertically and then take the maximum of each column:

```
np.vstack(list_of_arrays).max(axis=0)
```